# Alternative to SSL certificate?

Tags: security-certificate, amazon-aws, amazon-ec2, node-js

I wanted to make a fun joke website for my friends and I. I'm using 000webhost because I don't care to spend money, as we would use it for a week.

The website requires Node and a database. I set it all up but it doesn’t work because its not sending through `https`,without https you get this error:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://Mypage.example.com' was loaded
> over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://my-amazon-ec2'.
> This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Is there any services I can use to maybe send it through `https` or should I just give up? An SSL certificate can be a little pricey, and for a joke site it’s incredibly stupid to do.

Comment: There are alternative servers. If you are intending on using a browser, they use SSL.

Comment: Are you certain that 000webhost does not have a free SSL option in the control panel for the site?

Comment: [Recommendations for sites and resources](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) are considered off-topic here due to issues with self-promotion and spam. In addition to free SSL certificates you can generate yourself as Wayne covered, there are CDN's that provide them for free as well (e.g., CloudFlare).

Answer (score 3):

You can use a free SSL certificate.

The linode community, (mostly affiliates who make support videos or blogs and offer a coupon for starting linode account), seems to have the best help in setting up websites on a linux node/virtual machine/or bare metal. Which amazon also provides in the free tier levels.

**The how to install depends on which OS you are using in your node and which web server.**

Google your OS, (IE Ubuntu), and your server (IE node.js) and letsenrypt and you should find how to instructions.

### Let's Encrypt EFF's certbot (example)

https://certbot.eff.org/ has a snap install package goes something like this

```
sudo snap install core; sudo snap refresh core
sudo snap install --classic certbot
sudo ln -s /snap/bin/certbot /usr/bin/certbot
sudo certbot --apache
sudo certbot certonly --apache
```

and test the auto renew.

```
sudo certbot renew --dry-run
```

### Let's Encrypt from git (example)

```
sudo apt-get install git
sudo git clone https://github.com/letsencrypt/letsencrypt /opt/letsencrypt
cd /opt/letsencrypt
sudo -H ./letsencrypt-auto certonly --standalone -d example.com -d www.example.com
./letsencrypt-auto renew
```